# How to Read VPN Login Name?

Tags: c#, authentication, checkpoint

We have an application that needs a user to be connected to the VPN to run. THe issue is we rely on Windows Authentication for the application to be authenticated. However , we have come across some machines whose windows login name and their AD login Names are different.

Can somebody suggest a way for us to read the AD login name which is the same as the VPN login Name at all times ?
PS: we use checkpoint VPN Secure Client

Comment: if it sits on top of ActiveDirectory you can capture it that way..

Comment: Iam sorry, Could you let me know of a C# snippet that could do this

Comment: first of all I would actually need to see how you are getting the VPN login name or .. are you wanting to check the Login name against AD login name or sn

Comment: hi kraze, thanks for answering,  the issue is , i would like to get the ad login name , i tried using the enviorment variables , however they return me the local machine login  not the remote login name. Since the remote login name is same as the AD login name, i figured that if i could find if the vpn is connected, and if i could read the vpn login name , then that could be used as the ad login name

Comment: what ever you have code wise would help to assist you in what you are looking for..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this if you are using ActiveDirectory but I am not sure if you are familiar with AD but this will be a good learning tool for you especially if it works..

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string groupName = "Domain Users";
    string domainName = "";

    PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName);
    GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, groupName);

    if (grp != null)
    {
         foreach (Principal p in grp.GetMembers(false))
         {
                Console.WriteLine(p.SamAccountName + " - " + p.DisplayName);
         }

        grp.Dispose();
        ctx.Dispose();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nWe did not find that group in that domain, perhaps the group resides in a different domain?");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

or you can try that one specified in this link on [How to get Users Belonging to Active Directory group](http://www.dotnetactivedirectory.com/learn/How_to_get_Users_Belonging_to_Active_Directory_group.htm)

Comment: Hi Kraze,  Very sorry for the delay was away on a vacation , the workaround works cool .

Comment: Thanks a million for your effort kraze

Comment: Iam really sorry Kraze, I would have loved to vote up but there is a requirement of 15 points for the same, once I get 15 points, i will definitely vote up

Comment: not a problem I am just happy that the quick solution that I have provided was able to help you. thanks again